# How to filter for the most common problems with tcpdump/tshark

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump, tshark

I am currently using the following command in Linux to get specifics on network problems.

```
tshark -r file.pcap -q -z io,stat,1,\

"COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission",\

"COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack",\

"COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment) tcp.analysis.lost_segment",\

"COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission) tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission"
```

This outputs a nice table with lots of good information. However, I would like to know what other columns I could add to get more things like incorrect checksums, and something that could possibly point out network congestion. Pretty much anything needed to point out performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Network congestion is usually well handled by TCP itself using either [slow-start, congestion avoidance](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2581#section-3.1), or [fast-restransmit / fast-recovery](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2581#section-3.2) algorithms described in [RFC 2581](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2581). TCP will try to fix things up before significant congestion happens.

Now if you are in a very particular case, you could add the RTT measurement and it's variance, track the sender's window size (cwnd) and trace CWR and ECE flags appearance.

PS : Checksum processing is commonly offloaded to the NIC driver so it won't be a good metric to monitor as it will appear broken in libpcap-based tools.